# select nearest neighbours

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

consider the following data:

```
category | index | value
-------------------------
cat 1    | 1     | 2
cat 1    | 2     | 3
cat 1    | 3     |  
cat 1    | 4     | 1
cat 2    | 1     | 5
cat 2    | 2     |  
cat 2    | 3     |  
cat 2    | 4     | 6
cat 3    | 1     |  
cat 3    | 2     |  
cat 3    | 3     | 2 
cat 3    | 4     | 1
```

I am trying to fill in the holes, so that `hole = avg(value)` of 2 nearest neighbours with non-null values within a category:

```
category | index | value
-------------------------
cat 1    | 1     | 2
cat 1    | 2     | 3
cat 1    | 3     | 2*
cat 1    | 4     | 1
cat 2    | 1     | 5
cat 2    | 2     | 5.5*
cat 2    | 3     | 5.5* 
cat 2    | 4     | 6
cat 3    | 1     | 1.5*
cat 3    | 2     | 1.5* 
cat 3    | 3     | 2 
cat 3    | 4     | 1
```

I've been playing with window functions and am pretty sure it can be achieved but the solution is eluding me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are the values in between `2` and `6` averaged as `1.5` instead of `4` ?

Comment: Also, do you have to solve this problem using only Postgres?  I would have a hard time doing this in a tool like R or Matlab, both of which were designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: '6' is not in 'cat 3'. within cat 3, the nearest neighbours are 2 and 1.

Comment: postgresql only thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, window function is what you're looking for. Here's how it can be done (`with` part is used to define table, so you probably won't need it):

```
with dt as
(
    select * from
    (
        values
            ('cat 1', 1, 2),
            ('cat 1', 2, 3),
            ('cat 1', 3, null),
            ('cat 1', 4, 1),
            ('cat 2', 1, 5),
            ('cat 2', 2, null),
            ('cat 2', 3, null),
            ('cat 2', 4, 6),
            ('cat 3', 1, null),
            ('cat 3', 2, null),
            ('cat 3', 3, 1),
            ('cat 3', 4, 2)

    ) tbl ("category", "index", "value")
)
select
        "category",
        "index",
        case
            when "value" is null then (avg("value") over (partition by "category") )
            else "value"
        end
    from dt
    order by "category", "index";
```

refer to `WINDOW Clause` section of [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html) page for further info on window functions.

Comment: i had to do something slightly different involving an inner query and `row_number()` but your answer is excellent.

Answer (score -1):

I was working on a solution for you, but SQLfiddle is giving (internal) errors at the moment, so I can't complete it.

A statement like this should do the update for you:

```
update table1 as t1
set value = 
  (select avg(value)
   from 
   (select value
    from table1 as t3
    where t1.category = t3.category
    and   t3.index in (t1.index - 1, t1.index + 1)
    ) AS T2
   )
where value is null
;
```

The fiddle I was working on is here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/acbc2/1

Comment: index+1 and index-1 would not always be the nearest neighbours, since the missing row could be the first in the category or the hole could be 2x rows

Comment: The solution then would be to use `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions. I might be able to revise this later if sqlfiddle works for me. At the present I can't experiment.

Answer (score -2):

While I am sure its possible to make some hideously complicated and nested statement that does what you want, I wanted to say that, sometimes, its better to write a script in a regular programming language such as python/ruby/java that iterates over the DB table and makes whatever changes you want.

This will be a great deal more maintainable and you want have to rearchitect the whole thing every time you need to make any change to it (such as using 3 nearest neighbors instead, or changing the definition of 'nearest neighbor')

Comment: but also woefully inefficient!