# Filling nulls with average between neighbor values with restriction on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, partition-by

I have a table with column names "id", "time", "value"
and when "value" is null, I want it to be average between nearest neighbors by "time" column on that id

My problem is exactly that described here [select nearest neighbours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738642/select-nearest-neighbours/31738725), but the answer doesn't explain how can I find nearest neighbors with a restriction on another column (id should be the same)

Example:
in second row "value" is missing

```
id       | time  | value
-------------------------
11111    | 1     | 5.0
11111    | 10    | 
22222    | 7     | 32.6
33333    | 11    | 15.88
11111    | 15    | 20.0
```

and I want it to be:

```
id       | time  | value
-------------------------
11111    | 1     | 5.0
11111    | 10    | 12.5*
22222    | 7     | 32.6
33333    | 11    | 15.88
11111    | 15    | 20.0
```

as (20.0 + 5.0) / 2 = 12.5

How can it be obtained in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `time` defines the order and is unique (a unique column and one that defines the order is necessary for this), one method is to use subqueries getting the top (bottom) `value` of the records with a smaller (larger) `time` using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.time,
       coalesce(t1.value,
                ((SELECT t2.value
                         FROM elbat t2
                         WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                               AND t2.time < t1.time
                         ORDER BY t2.time DESC
                         LIMIT 1)
                 +
                 (SELECT t2.value
                         FROM elbat t2
                         WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                               AND t2.time > t1.time
                         ORDER BY t2.time ASC
                         LIMIT 1)
                )
                /
                2) value
       FROM elbat t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=240623d80fcd76eb113b44c4d660e0ab)

But this only can fill gaps one row wide. If there can be larger gaps you'd have to define what are the next non null neighbours of these rows.

Answer (score 0):

### just join self, but be care for no NEXT_VALUE

```
SELECT ID_,
   TIME_,
   CASE
      WHEN VALUE_ IS NULL THEN (LAST_VALUE + NEXT_VALUE) / 2
      ELSE VALUE_
   END AS REAL_VALUE
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ ORDER BY TIME_ DESC)
              NOW_ROW_NUM,
           ID_,
           TIME_,
           VALUE_
      FROM TESTTABLE)
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER ()
                         OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ ORDER BY TIME_ DESC))
                     - 1
                        LAST_ROW_NUM,
                     ID_ AS LAST_ID,
                     VALUE_ AS LAST_VALUE
                FROM TESTTABLE)
      ON ID_ = LAST_ID AND NOW_ROW_NUM = LAST_ROW_NUM
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER ()
                         OVER (PARTITION BY ID_ ORDER BY TIME_ DESC))
                     + 1
                        NEXT_ROW_NUM,
                     ID_ AS NEXT_ID,
                     VALUE_ AS NEXT_VALUE
                FROM TESTTABLE)
      ON ID_ = LAST_ID AND NOW_ROW_NUM = NEXT_ROW_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lead()` and `lag()`.  The simplest answer is:

```
selet t.*
      (case when value is null
            then ( lag(value) over (partition by id order by time) + lead(value) over (partition by id order by time) ) / 2
            else value
       end) as new_value
from t;
```

This does not work for the first or last values.  You can instead use:

```
selet t.*
      (case when value is null
            then ( avg(value) over (partition by id order by time rows between 1 preceding and 1 following)
            else value
       end) as new_value
from t;
```

This calculates the average based on available data in the preceding and succeeding rows.